# Print program usage example with argparse module

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to learn how to use python's `argparse` module. Currently my python script is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My first argparse attempt',
                                add_help=True)
parser.add_argument("-q", action ="store", dest='argument',
                    help="First argument")
output = parser.parse_args()
```

And it gives the output as :

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-q ARGUMENT]

My first argparse attempt

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -q ARGUMENT  First argument
```

Now, lets suppose I want my `-h or --help` argument to print a `usage example` also. Like,

```
   Usage: python test.py -q "First Argument for test.py"
```

My purpose is to print the above usage example along with the default content of `-h` argument so that the user can get a basic idea of how to use the `test.py` python script.

So, is this functionality inbuilt in the `argparse` module. If no than what is the correct way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [`parser.epilog`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#epilog) to display something after the generated `-h` text.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='My first argparse attempt',
    epilog='Example of use')

output = parser.parse_args()
```

prints:

```
My first argparse attempt

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

Example of use
```

Comment: @Noob -- Note that whitespace will be stripped from your description and epilog (which is often not good for "Examples of Use".  To allow that you want the `argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter`  ( http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter )

Comment: Is there a way to use argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter just for the epilog and not for the description? I want the description to be wrapped automatically. but I want to take care of the formatting of epilogue.

Comment: Please add note about `RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` so that we can +1 this answer.