# argparse add example usage

Tags: python, argparse

I use argparse to deal with input parameters, and it outputs the following with parser.print_help():

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -t TEMPLATES, --templates TEMPLATES
                    template names to make, should be defined as section
                    name in conf, and have related file in templates/
                    folder
  -c CONFPATH, --confpath CONFPATH
                    configuration path for template detail info
```

my code looks like the following:

```
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='base_maker', description='template maker')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--templates', help='template names to make, should be defined as section name in conf, and have related file in templates/ folder', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--confpath', help='configuration path for template detail info', type=str, default=os.path.join(basepath, 'conf/maker.conf'))
```

However, I want to add a detailed example about how to use -t/--template, like (added in the **example** part):

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -t TEMPLATES, --templates TEMPLATES
                    template names to make, should be defined as section
                    name in conf, and have related file in templates/
                    folder
  -c CONFPATH, --confpath CONFPATH
                    configuration path for template detail info

 example:

     python test.py -t template/test.py
     python test.py -t template/test -c conf/test.conf
     python test.py -t test.py
```

I don't know which attribute should be used to add "example" part, I check [Print program usage example with argparse modulen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930635/print-program-usage-example-with-argparse-module), but it's unclear and without detailed example when I check [epilog in the official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#epilog).

Could anyone give me a example about how to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the mentioned `epilog`? What's wrong with it?

Comment: yes,  but how to change line inside it, I want to have multi-lines of explanation, and then I wonder whether there is a better way for it

Comment: Have you tried passing a `"""multiline string"""` to `epilog`? I'd guess that would do it, line breaks within that will be retained. You can keep it neat as I show [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60369/32391).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to use the epilog and the formatter_class arguments to ArgumentParser if you want to have the help the example printed at the end (epilog) and to preserve the whitespace/formatting (formatter_class set to RawDescriptionHelpFormatter).

Example by modifying your example above:

```
import argparse

example_text = '''example:

 python test.py -t template/test.py
 python test.py -t template/test -c conf/test.conf
 python test.py -t test.py'''

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='base_maker',
                                 description='template maker',
                                 epilog=example_text,
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument('-t', '--templates', help='template names to make, should be defined as section name in conf, and have related file in templates/ folder', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-c', '--confpath', help='configuration path for template detail info', type=str, default=os.path.join(basepath, 'conf/maker.conf'))
```

Comment: Accurate, thanks, it needs formatter_class setting :)

Comment: I"m already using the `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter`. Guess I have to roll my own then?

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the program name, you can use `$(prog)s` in the example text: `example_text = "$(prog)s -t template/test.py"`, for example.

Comment: @famzah the specifier is actually `%(prog)s` and not `$(prog)s`

Comment: @pranavashok, you are right! Thanks. The correct example is: ```example_text = "%(prog)s -t template/test.py"```

Comment: @ThomasAhle You can create your own class that inherits from both: `class Formatter(argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter): pass`